# how to get the login user details with forms authetication

Tags: forms-authentication

i am using forms authentication ,once the user logs in i am trying to get the user name by using    user.identity.name

```
     btnLogout.Text = "Welcome" + User.Identity.Name;
```

once the user logs in it is redirected to home page there i want to get username using above,but it is returning windows credentials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your web config needs to be configured to use Forms Authentication. Windows is the default.